# Minor difference between going-up and going-down theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I've been studying commutative algebra and fascinated yet confused by the subject. The going-up and going-down theorem somewhat bother me.
The statement of these two theorems are quite the same(symmetrical) but still some minor difference(that is, the "integral domain and integrally closed" condition in the going-down theorem), it would be great if we can further abstract the idea and unify these two theorems.
So, are there any higher abstraction where these two theorems are "coherent and symmetrical"?

Comment: Atiyah-MacDonald, Exercise 5.10

Comment: @math54321 oh, thanks.